# XeLaTeX cannot map letters with diacritics correctly?

Tags: fonts, xetex, accents

I found that XeLaTeX cannot map letters with more than two diacritics correctly. For example, `\v{\"{u}}` or `\v{ü}` cannot produce  the expected ǚ correctly. I've tried many fonts, so I think it may not depend on fonts. Any tricky way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: It is font dependent. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12562/missing-glyph-in-texgyretermes-font

Comment: Why don’t you just use ǚ directly? At least with some fonts it produces better results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It certainly does depend on the font.  Here's a selection from my machine (a Mac).

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfamily\libertine{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\times{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\charis{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily\minion{Minion Pro}
\newfontfamily\luxiserif{Luxi Serif}
\newfontfamily\biolinum{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\lmr{Latin Modern Roman}
\newfontfamily\junicode{Junicode}
\newfontfamily\cambria{Cambria}
\newfontfamily\arialmt{Arial Unicode MS}
\newfontfamily\doulos{Doulos SIL}
\newcommand{\testchar}{\v{\"{u}} or \v{ü}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
Linux Libertine O &{\libertine\testchar}\\
Junicode & {\junicode\testchar}\\
Charis SIL &{\charis\testchar}\\
Doulos SIL & {\doulos\testchar}\\
Latin Modern &{\lmr\testchar}\\
Times New Roman &{\times\testchar}\\
Minion Pro &{\minion\testchar}\\
Luxi Serif & {\luxiserif\testchar}\\
Linux Biolinum O & {\biolinum\testchar}\\
Cambria & {\cambria\testchar}\\
Arial Unicode MS & {\arialmt\testchar}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Linux Libertine does not work for me on Linux. Might be OS dependent.

Comment: @Caramdir Linux Libertine or Linux Libertine O?  Or maybe you have duplicate fonts in your system?

Comment: Linux Libertine O (I just copied your example and removed all other fonts (as I don't have most of them).

Comment: @Caramdir Do Charis SIL or Junicode work?

Comment: Charis SIL works. Maybe I have an outdated version of Linux Libertine O.

Comment: Yes. Version 4.7.5 (from the website) works, while 4.4.1 (from Ubuntu packages) doesn't.

Comment: haha, Cambria works for me.